# iBeaconでExitRegionからEnterRegionになるまでに時間がかかる場合があります

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon

ビーコンの検知までに時間がかかる事象が発生しています。

再現手順は、
①[self findBeacon]; を実行して検知を開始する
②ビーコンをＯＮにする
③「EnterRegion.」「CLRegionStateInside.」が表示される
④「FindBeacon.」が表示されビーコンを検知
⑤ビーコンをＯＦＦ
⑥しばらくすると「ExitRegion」「CLRegionStateOutside」が表示される
⑦ビーコンをＯＮにする

この後に「EnterRegion.」「CLRegionStateInside.」が表示されるまでに時間がかかる場合があります。
iPhone5(iOS8.4.1)で試しているんですが、30秒程度かかる場合もあれば２、３秒で表示される場合もあります。
別の端末だと、２分以上かかる場合もありました。

「EnterRegion.」にならないとビーコンが検知されないようなので困っています。

実装のやり方として間違っているところがありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

```
- (void)findBeacon {
  CLLocationManager *locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
  [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"startMonitoring");
  [manager requestStateForRegion:region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
  switch (state) {
    case CLRegionStateInside:
      NSLog(@"CLRegionStateInside");
      CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion*)region;
      [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
      break;
    case CLRegionStateOutside:
      NSLog(@"CLRegionStateOutside");
      break;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"EnterRegion.");
  [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"ExitRegion.");
  [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
  NSLog(@"FindBeacon.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

参考になるかわかりませんが、気になったところを幾つか書かせて頂きます。

- `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`の実行が多い
  iBeacon領域外から領域内に入った場合、`didDetermineState`と`didEnterRegion`が呼ばれます。また、既にiBeacon領域にいる状態でアプリを起動すると、`didDetermineState`のみ呼ばれます。(**didEnterRegion**は呼ばれません)
  なので、私の場合は`startRangingBeaconsInRegion`を`didDetermineState`の`CLRegionStateInside`を通った時のみにしています。
- `requestStateForRegion`の実行について
  一連の流れとしては、アプリをフォアグラウンド起動させっぱなしの話かと思います。
  私の場合は既にiBeacon領域内にいる状態でアプリを起動したところ、
  `didDetermineState`が呼ばれなかったため、
  `requestStateForRegion`を実行してiBeaconを検知するようにしていました。

因みに、端末の電源がOFFの状態からONにした直後はiBeaconを検知してくれませんでした。
後は特に問題なさそうに見えます。

何かの参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご指摘のとおり、startRangingBeaconsInRegionを呼ぶのは、didDetermineStateのCLRegionStateInsideの時のみにしようと思います。
実装に関して後は特に問題なし、ということで安心しました。ありがとうございました。